# iterate int xml file using ant

Tags: xml, parsing, ant

I´ve a Xml file with the struct below. I want to read the nod by node and call a specific task with the values without commom separator.In Ant this is possible ?

```
<projects>
<!-- first node -->
 <project>
    <name> </name>
    <url> </url>
    <package> </package>
 </project>

 <!-- Second node -->
 <project>
    <name> </name>
    <url> </url>
    <package> </package>
 </project>
<projects>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [XSLT](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html) task to process the input XML file into an ANT script that is subsequently executed.

## Example

```
|-- build.xml
|-- projects-process.xsl
`-- projects.xml
```

Running will process the information in the

```
$ ant
Buildfile: /home/mark/tmp/build.xml

run-projects:
     [xslt] Processing /home/mark/tmp/projects.xml to /home/mark/tmp/build-tmp.xml
     [xslt] Loading stylesheet /home/mark/tmp/projects-process.xsl

build:

dosomething:
     [echo] DOSOMETHING: 'Project 1' 'http://someurl1' 'project1'"

dosomething:
     [echo] DOSOMETHING: 'Project 2' 'http://someurl2' 'project2'"

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

### projects.xml

```
<projects>

    <project>
        <name>Project 1</name>
        <url>http://someurl1</url>
        <package>project1</package>
    </project>

    <project>
        <name>Project 2</name>
        <url>http://someurl2</url>
        <package>project2</package>
    </project>

</projects>
```

### projects-process.xsl

This XSLT stylesheet is used to generate an ANT script

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <project name="genbuild" default="build">

            <target name="build">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="projects/project"/>
            </target>

            <target name="dosomething">
                <echo>DOSOMETHING: '${name}' '${url}' '${package}'"</echo>
            </target>

        </project>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="project">
        <antcall target="dosomething">
            <param name="name"    value="{name}"/>
            <param name="url"     value="{url}"/>
            <param name="package" value="{package}"/>
        </antcall>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### build.xml

Runs the XSLT transform to process the **projects.xml** file and generate an ANT build file

```
<project name="demo" default="run-projects">

    <target name="run-projects">
        <xslt style="projects-process.xsl" in="projects.xml" out="build-tmp.xml"/>

        <ant antfile="build-tmp.xml"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete file="build-tmp.xml"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ant projects cannot be nested within the same Ant build file. However, build logic can be modularized using [MacroDefs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html). In addition, subprojects can have their own build files, which may be called from a master build file using the [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) Ant task. Ant targets may be called within the same build file using the [AntCall task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html).

Comment: Thanks to your answser! I solved the problem doing this:
    <xmltask source="stub-config.xml">
    <call path="//project">
    <param name="name" path="name/text()" />
    <param name="icon" path="icon/text()" />
    <param name="package" path="package/text()" />
    <actions>
    <echo>@{name}</echo>
    <echo> @{icon}</echo>
    <echo>@{package}</echo>
    <echo>${line.separator}</echo>
    <antcall target="do-something" />
    </actions>
    </call>
    </xmltask>

Answer (score 0):

thiagolsilva,

Using a combination of xmlproperty and javascript I was able to split a multi-element (same node) of a  projects.xml file and use project node data fields in ant.  All actions are performed in a single ant file, in a single execution.

The sample data projects.xml file from the example above:

```
<projects>
    <project>
        <name>Project 1</name>
        <url>//someurl1</url>
        <package>project1</package>
    </project>
    <project>
        <name>Project 2</name>
        <url>//someurl2</url>
        <package>project2</package>
    </project>
</projects>
```

Has to be transformed into following format of projects.xml file:

```
<myProjects>
    <!-- name;url;package -->
    <myProject>Project 1;//someurl1;project1</myProject>
    <myProject>Project 2;//someurl2;project2</myProject>
</myProjects>
```

Here, the previous  node elements were transformed into a single string with fields separated by ‘;’ character.

I have renamed the element “project” to “myProject” to avoid confusion, as I will be using ant “project” object in javascript.

Once we have flattened the repeatable xml node into a string, we can use the following ant script to iterate through the  elements, read the flattened  properties and use them as we wish.

```
<project name="testProjects" default="ProcessProjects" basedir=".">

  <target name="init" >
  <!-- From: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/ant-contrib/ 
     download the jar and put it a created "lib" folder of your project, where ant file is.
  -->
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
      <classpath><pathelement location="./lib/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/></classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <xmlproperty file="./projects.xml" keepRoot="false"/>

    <!-- Properties will be used to store the values of: name;url;package -->
    <property name="name" value=""/>
    <property name="url" value=""/>
    <property name="package" value=""/>
  </target>

  <target name="ProcessProjects" depends="init">
    <echo>Process Projects</echo>
    <foreach list="${myProject}" target="processLoopStep" param="var1"/>
  </target>

  <target name="processLoopStep" >
    <script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[
      var var1 = project.getProperty("var1");
      var parts = var1.split(";");
      project.setProperty("name",parts[0]);
      project.setProperty("url",parts[1]);
      project.setProperty("package",parts[2]);
      ]]>
    </script>

    <!-- Do what you like with the values of the <project> element -->
    <echo message="myProject name = ${name} url = ${url} package = ${package}"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

The files in:
 - C:\temp\lib\ProcessProjects.xml    - the build
 - C:\temp\lib\projects.xml           - the data
 - C:\temp\lib\ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar  - the lib jar

The output:

```
C:\temp>ant -f ProcessProjects.xml

Buildfile: C:\temp\ProcessProjects.xml
init:
ProcessProjects:
     [echo] Process Projects
processLoopStep:
     [echo] myProject name = Project 1 url = //someurl1 package = project1
processLoopStep:
     [echo] myProject name = Project 2 url = //someurl2 package = project2
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Regards, Jurek

Comment: How do you do the listed above transforamtion ? I've got the following  <Problem>
        <Rule>Microsoft.Design#SR0010</Rule>        <Severity>Warning</Severity>
</Problem><Problem>
        <Rule>Microsoft.Design#SR0010</Rule>        <Severity>Warning</Severity>
</Problem>