# Best data structure for ANT like Utility

Tags: data-structures, ant

Trying to make an ANT like utility wherein I am loading a configuration.xml ( similar to ant build.xml ). This configuration.xml has different 'target' tags that need to be executed based on the target attributes and properties. Each target has 'dependent' targets, which must be executed prior to executing the calling target

Which is the Best data structure for such processing ?

Currently I am using HASHMAP together with a Stack
I am reading the configuration.xml by SAX parser and loading each target as an object ( with all its properties and dependencies onto a HASHMAP.)

This Hashmap is then iterated, and dependencies are kept on stack. Once the stack is build, it is poped and each target executed.

Is this the Optimum solution or any better data structure ?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use an XSLT transformation and generate ANT file that is dynamically executed. The following example illustrates the principle:

- [iterate int xml file using ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528653/iterate-int-xml-file-using-ant/11529845#11529845)

But perhaps a better approach is to use a dynamic scripting language like groovy and create a custom DSL language for your application.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Actually I have decided to make a java utility for this. Was just wondering on the right choice of data structures to implements. Possible solution I can think of : 1.) hashmap + stack. But is this the optimum way of doing this ?